# In my docker-compose file, how can I set two env vars to the same thing without hard-coding the string twice?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I'm trying to construct a Docker container in which I have two environment variables set to the same thing.  I have

```
version: "3.2"
services:

  sql-server-db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
    ports:
      - 3900:1433
    env_file: ./tests/.test_env
    ...
    command: /bin/bash /my-app/my-script.sh
```

and then in my tests/.test_env file I have

```
MY_DB_PASSWORD=reallylongpassword
SA_PASSWORD=${MY_DB_PASSWORD}
```

I would like to set the "MY_DB_PASSWORD" and "SA_PASSWORD" env vars to the same thing, however, the above doesn't do it, because "SA_PASSWORD" seems to be set to the literal string "${MY_DB_PASSWORD}".  How do I set my two variables to the same thing without hard-coding the "reallylongpassword" string twice?

Comment: HI. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately, still don't know the answer here.

Comment: I tried your .test_env in a linux environment and works as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Glq4.png Are you in windows?

Comment: I'm on Mac.  But you're saying in Linux the "${MY_DB_PASSWORD}" was not interpreted as the literal string "${MY_DB_PASSWORD}" but rather was treated as an expression?

Comment: Yes. In linux works!! And since almost all the docker application are not designed to run on windows or mac servers, your goal must  be a success execution on linux.

Comment: I tested it (`SA_PASSWORD=${MY_DB_PASSWORD}`) again in Arch Linux - and now it works for me. Hence I deleted my answer below. Maybe update Docker Compose @Dave? Regardless which environment - Docker compose uses `python-dotenv`. This _should_ work anywhere I would assume.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using env file, simply do in your script [like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts/122878). This way is more flexible as it will take the value if not set.

```
SA_PASSWORD="${SA_PASSWORD:-$MY_DB_PASSWORD}"
```

If you are worry about password security, you should use docker secret but you need to run in Swarm mode.

Here is the dockerfile used by the [image](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/windows/mssql-server-windows/dockerfile). You can define your own CMD to override the behavior and take your env or use the trick to take default value.

```
CMD .\start -sa_password $env:sa_password -ACCEPT_EULA $env:ACCEPT_EULA -attach_dbs \"$env:attach_dbs\" -Verbose

//using you MY_DB_PASSWORD instead of SA_PASSWORD
CMD .\start -sa_password $env:my_db_password -ACCEPT_EULA $env:ACCEPT_EULA -attach_dbs \"$env:attach_dbs\" -Verbose
```

Comment: The docker image "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest" requires an "SA_PASSWORD" variable to be defined or it cannot startup.  If I define the "SA_PASSWORD" var in the script, /my-app/my-script.sh, the image won't be able to read it.

Comment: SQLServer is started using CMD, you can define your CMD to override default behavior and run a custom script to set the env before starting SQL server

Comment: So that "CMD" is the last thing you define in the Dockerfile?  How do you define "my_db_password" ?  Is that also defined in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, you put CMD in last in your file, then you can keep your env_file as before but you only need one variable MY_DB_PASSWORD as the command line is not using the other one anymore.